# Template missing in render :file in ajax call when the file exists in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Ajax is used for Bootstrap modal call. The `js.erb` file is called successfully and this `js.erb` file then should load `html.erb` residing in the same subdir as the `js.erb` is under `biz_workflowz/app/views/application/`. Here is the `js.erb` file:

```
$("#newworkflow .modal-content").html('<%= j render(:file => "/biz_workflowx/application/event_action.html.erb") %>');
$("#newworkflow").modal();
```

However the `event_action.html.erb` is never found. The error is raised in `action_view/path_sets.rb`:

```
def find(*args)
  find_all(*args).first || raise(MissingTemplate.new(self, *args)) #find_all(*args).first returns NIL
end
```

The error is:

```
    ActionView::Template::Error (Missing template c:/d/code/rails_proj/engines/biz_workflowx/app/views/application/event_action.html.erb with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee]}. Searched in:
   .......
      * "C:/D/code/rails_proj/engines/biz_workflowx/app/views" #<<== did search the subdir but did not find anything
      * "C:/D/code/rails_proj/engines/searchx/app/views"
      * "C:/D/code/rails_proj/engines/commonx/app/views"
      * "C:/D/code/rails_proj/engines/authentify/app/views"
      * "C:/D/code/rails_proj/webportal"
      * "C:/"
    ):
        1: $("#newworkflow .modal-content").html('<%= j render(:file => "biz_workflowx/application/event_action.html.erb") %>');
        2: $("#newworkflow").modal();
      actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:46:in `find'
```

Even with hardcoded path to the file `event_action.html.erb`, it still returns `template missing`. The similar `js.erb` code has been used in a few places for ajax call and I does not see why here it does not work. What could cause this error?

### Updated

Here is the debug windows showing the `biz_workflowz/app/views` has been searched by `resolver` which does not see the file under `/application/`. Strange!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

add `event_action.html.erb` file under `c:/d/code/rails_proj/engines/biz_workflowx/app/views/application`